# Нужно вывести по ключу значение поля другой таблицы

Tags: python, django

Есть следующие модели:

```
class ARM (models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'arm'
network = models.ManyToManyField(Network)
arm_configuration_name = models.TextField()

class Network(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'network'
network_name = models.TextField()
```

В шаблон передаю так (views.py):

```
def Display_example(request):
    arms = ARM.objects.all()
    rooms = Room.objects.all()
    network = Network.objects.all()
    server = Server.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'example.html', {'arms': arms
                                        '    network': network})
```

Нужно в шаблоне вывести всю информацию о АРМ'е (в т.ч. и к какой сети относится). Пробую так:

```
{% for arm in arms %}
<div>
 <p>{{ arm.arm_configuration_name }}</p>
 {% for network in networks %}
     {% if network.id == arm.network %}
        <p>{{ network.network_name }}</p>
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Но информация о том, к какой сети относится АРМ, не выводится. Не совсем понимаю почему.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужно поле network именно типа ManyToMany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется вы пытаетесь сравнивать 2 поля разных типов в строке `{% if network.id == arm.network %}`, первое - скорее всего целое число, второе - экземпляр Network.

Думаю, правильнее будет немного изменить код:

```
{% for network in arm.network.all %}
    <p>{{ network.network_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

[Вот здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) очень подробно, понятно и с примерами описано, как работать с полями типа ManyToMany.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло. Обязательно почитаю документацию.